# How to use the bitmap generated by ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail?

Tags: android, video

I understand that ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail will generate a thumbnail of a video. But how to use the bitmap file that is the result of the process? Should I add another ImageView to hold that thumbnail bitmap? VideoView itself does not seem to be able to display an bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use Imageview, to which you will set the bitmap generated from ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail class. VideoView will not be able to display the bitmap generated.

Comment: Then, how do I add the play icon to the ImageView? Do I need another imageview on top of the one holding the thumbnail?